# Can't get rows from DB using ->where()->get();

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I ve got table in data base called invoices and columns automonth and autoyear with values. I don't know why this function returns empty array. I want to get rows with automonth value and autoyear value. Please help me.

```
$autoyear = date('Y');
$automonth = date('m');

$autonumber = DB::table("invoices as invoices")
    ->where('automonth', '=', '$automonth')
    ->where('autoyear', '=', '$autoyear') 
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove quotes from **$automonth** and **$autoyear** :

```
$autonumber = DB::table("invoices as invoices")
    ->where('automonth', '=', $automonth)
    ->where('autoyear', '=', $autoyear) 
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

you pass your variable in a wrong way:

```
$autonumber = DB::table("invoices as invoices")
    ->where('automonth', '=', $automonth)
    ->where('autoyear', '=', $autoyear) 
    ->get();
```

there is no need of '' when you pass the your variable names ...